# NodeJs - How to share MySQL pool accross my models to avoid 'ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR'

Tags: mysql, node.js, connection-pooling

I'm currently testing my node app using ApacheBench. I run into an issue with my database which is `ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR: Too many connections`.

I'm using a short library on the top of MySQL node module that you can see just below

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var config = require('path/to/config');
var message = require('./myMessageLib.js');

var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 100,
    host: config.db.mysql.host,
    user: config.db.mysql.user,
    password: config.db.mysql.password,
    database: config.db.mysql.database
});

var query = function(query_str, values, next) {
    pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error("MySQL Fail to get a connection in pool : " + err);
            if (typeof connection !== "undefined")
                connection.release();
            next(error, null);
            return ;
        }
        connection.query(query_str, values, function(error, data, fields) {
            connection.release();
            if (error) 
                if (config.app.env.dev)
                    throw (error);
                else {
                    next(error, null);
                    return (message.error("MySQL query failed : " + query_str + " / err : " + error));
                }
            if (data.length == 0)
                next(null);
            else
                next(data);
        })
    })
}

exports.query = query;
```

I use this library in my model by doing something like this

```
var mysql = require('path/to/mysqllib');

/**
 * Class PlayerModel
 */
function PlayerModel() { };

PlayerModel.prototype.get = function(id, next) {
    mysql.query("SELECT ....", [id], function(player) {
        // stuff
    })
}

module.exports = PlayerModel;
```

The things is on my homepage I use different models like the one presented above and each one launch a query to get some database information. When I launch an ApacheBench with only 50 concurrency levels I got the ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR: Too many connections. So I've got the feeling that the pool isn't well made because it seems that it didn't respect the connections limit of 100 written in the short MySQL lib.

I was thinking about creating and storing the pool in the `global` nodejs variable to be able to share it correctly accros my modules but I'm not sure it's a good way and maybe also I'm doing something wrong on my pool implentation.

Do you have any idea or improvements to suggest ?

Thanks mates!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue.

My app was deploying in cluster mode. Two process were running at the same time. Because of that, two pools of 100 connections could have been created which is resulting on a total of 200 connections which is higher than the MySQL default connection limit.

Comment: If you still require clustering, you can simply create the connection pool inside the `if (cluster.isMaster) { ... }` block. Check [cluster.isMaster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster_ismaster) for mode info.

Answer (score 0):

Great that found a solution and here's another one with less code.

create a js file, **dbconnection.js** for example

```
var mysql   = require("mysql");

var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 10,
    host: '...',
    user: '...',
    password: '...',
    database: '...',
    dateStrings: true
});

exports.connection = {
    query: function () {
        var queryArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
            events = [],
            eventNameIndex = {};

        pool.getConnection(function (err, conn) {
            if (err) {
                if (eventNameIndex.error) {
                    eventNameIndex.error();
                }
            }
            if (conn) { 
                var q = conn.query.apply(conn, queryArgs);
                q.on('end', function () {
                    conn.release();
                });

                events.forEach(function (args) {
                    q.on.apply(q, args);
                });
            }
        });

        return {
            on: function (eventName, callback) {
                events.push(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
                eventNameIndex[eventName] = callback;
                return this;
            }
        };
    }
};
```

In the other file where you want to use the connection

```
var db = require('./dbconnection.js');
```

And instead of

```
connection.query
```

Use

```
db.connection.query
```